# passport local strategy is not getting called

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Here is my route handler:

```
exports.login = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password)
        next();
    passport.authenticate('local');
};
```

I know that this is getting executed when I submit the login form and that `req.body.username` and `req.body.password` contain values - express bodyParser is doing its thing (I have set a breakpoint there).

Here is my local strategy:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        function(username, password, done) {
            console.log('local strategy called with: %s', username);
            var User = bsHelper.getModelFromResource('users');
            User.findOne({ where: {
                email_text: username,
                password_hash: password
            } })
                .then(
                function (user) {
                    if (!user) {
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email.' });
                    }
                    return done(null, user);
                },
                function(err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
            );
        }
    ));
```

The statement at the top of the verify callback is not logged to the console.

I don't know what else to test. I have tried upgrading to the latest version of passport...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `passport.authenticate('local')` it actually returns a function in express router callback style. So you can either invoke the function or pass it in router callback:

```
exports.login = passport.authenticate('local')
```

or

```
exports.login = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password)
        next();
    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, next) ;
};
```